# Styling the background of all the paper-fab[icon="add"] icons

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to style all the paper fab add icons at my page:

`<paper-fab icon="add" mini></paper-fab>`

The default styling is:
[image]

but I want the paper fab icon to have the default accent color as background color:

[image]

I can do this styling with:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --paper-fab-background: var(--accent-color);
  }
</style>
```

But then I would change the background color of all paper fab icons, I only want to change the background color of the `paper-fab[icon="add"]` icons. Any ideas?

here is the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5FhiV4?p=preview

working demo (thanks to answer): http://plnkr.co/edit/ag0pmZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this in your `style[is=custom-style]`.

```
html /deep/ paper-fab[icon="add"] {
  background: green; /* or whatever your color is */
}
```

Custom CSS Properties are still CSS properties that can be applied to an element if that element supports it.

Comment: My first edit was wrong. While this certainly works, please do refrain from using `/deep/` or `::shadow` selectors as they may be deprecated soon.

Comment: thanks ! but if those get deprecated, how could I do this in the future ?

Comment: They're still trying to figure some stuff out but we may be able to see some new CSS selectors and/or syntax soon I suppose.